# Apach solr. query syntax explanation

Tags: java, solr

I messed with syntax q query:

1. if I write `q=*:*` - I see 2 results.
2. If I skip q - I have not see anything
3. if I write `q=price:*` - see 2 results
4. if I write `q=price` - 0 results

**update**

1. `q=price:0` - 1 result

Can you explain differences between these queries?

especially I want to understand what does it mean 4 th variant ?

indexed documents:

```
add><doc>
  <field name="id">3007WFP</field>
  <field name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</field>
  <field name="manu">Dell, Inc.</field>
  <!-- Join -->
  <field name="manu_id_s">dell</field>
  <field name="cat">electronics</field>
  <field name="cat">monitor</field>
  <field name="features">30" TFT active matrix LCD, 2560 x 1600, .25mm dot pitch, 700:1 contrast</field>
  <field name="includes">USB cable</field>
  <field name="weight">401.6</field>
  <field name="price">2199</field>
  <field name="popularity">6</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
  <!-- Buffalo store -->
  <field name="store">43.17614,-90.57341</field>
  <field name="cat">XXX</field>
 </doc></add>
```

---

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="id">SOLR1000</field>
  <field name="name">Solr, the Enterprise Search Server</field>
  <field name="manu">Apache Software Foundation</field>
  <field name="cat">software</field>
  <field name="cat">search</field>
  <field name="cat">XXX</field>
  <field name="features">Advanced Full-Text Search Capabilities using Lucene</field>
  <field name="features">Optimized for High Volume Web Traffic</field>
  <field name="features">Standards Based Open Interfaces - XML and HTTP</field>
  <field name="features">Comprehensive HTML Administration Interfaces</field>
  <field name="features">Scalability - Efficient Replication to other Solr Search Servers</field>
  <field name="features">Flexible and Adaptable with XML configuration and Schema</field>
  <field name="features">Good unicode support: h&#xE9;llo (hello with an accent over the e)</field>
  <field name="price">0</field>
  <field name="popularity">10</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
  <field name="incubationdate_dt">2006-01-17T00:00:00.000Z</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not give the value it consider the default value. As in your fourth query

```
q=price means it searches the default searchable field having value "price"
```

That's why you are getting 0 result since no price is of 0 value.

Comment: *q=price:0* - 1 result

Comment: Check your solrconfig.xml for the default searchable field. On that field solr is making query and whose value is "price".

Comment: what tag Do I need to search?

Comment: 1.in solr instance  I have a lot of solrconfig.xml. 2 Which tag(within necessary solrconfig.xml) Does set *the default searchable field* ?

Comment: For every requestHandeler you can set the default searchable field. For your "select" request Handler you can have <str name="df">content</str>. Default searchable field name is df.

Comment: 2. After I found necessary solrconfig.xml - how to find *default searchable field* within solrconfig.xml